# March 6, 2013, access tokens and /me/accounts/

Tags: migration, access-token, facebook-page

So. According to the pending March 6th changes, I have question regarding the "Removing apps from /me/accounts/ and page_admin FQL table" change.

This change seems, to me, imply that you are also going to remove "`/<user_id>/accounts/`" - is this the case?

Because I'm using "`/<user_id>/accounts/`" to get non-expiring access tokens (c.f. https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/#page_access_token).

Cheers!

Tomage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the roadmaps states they will "longer show **apps** under /me/accounts/". The endpoint, with access to Pages, will still be there. Just the apps that are currently in that list will not be. If you want to get the apps they are a developer of, the docs state " hit /me/applications/developer/ or use the app_role FQL table."

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2013/02/27/platform-updates--operation-developer-love/